# Is there any way to get all process events in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, events

For example, instead of listening to a specific error like the one below:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', r => {
    console.error('tracing unhandledRejection: ');
    console.error(r.response);
});
```

I want to get all the process events, and just filter out the events I want through a config. 
Target behaviour I am looking into:

```js
process.on('events', event => {
   if (event is 'unhandledRejection') {
     doSomething();
   }
   else if(event is 'uncaughtException') {
     doSomethingElse();
   }
   else {
     ignore();
   }
});
```

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, process is a class which is extending "EventEmitter". It seems that you can not list or access all the "process" events.

Basically, an EventEmitter class has a .listeners() methods which is listing all the listeners opened, but you need to add your listener before if you want it on the .listeners() method.

If you really want to do it with a "custom" and "ugly" method, you can do something like this :

```
const events = ["beforeExit", "rejectionHandled", "uncaughtException", "exit"]; // list all the process events here...

events.forEach((eventName) => {
    console.log('listening on ', eventName);
    process.on(eventName, (...args) => {
        console.log('event ' + eventName + ' was called with args : ' + args.join(','));
    });
});

// quit process with exit code for example
process.exit(5);

// will be print :
// listening on  beforeExit
// listening on  rejectionHandled
// listening on  uncaughtException
// listening on  exit
// event exit was called with args : 5
```

Comment: And for process events, you can find them here : https://nodejs.org/api/process.html